# Image is not fitting round div? It is going out of the div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to wrap a image in rounded div but I cant figure out what i'm doing wrong. My div is okey it is rounded but I want my image to be fit in round box but why it is not fitting why It is going out, I'm new to html and css. Here is the code i'm sharing below help me out here.

```css
body {
  background: #F6F6F6;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 6px solid #19ab8c;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/567285191169687553/7kg_TF4l.jpeg" width="200"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you should overflow:hidden here in wrapper div.

Comment: Wrapper class relative

Comment: And overflow hidden as my other friend said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `overflow: hidden;` in .wrapper class try this code snippent below

```css
body {
  background: #F6F6F6;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 6px solid #19ab8c;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/567285191169687553/7kg_TF4l.jpeg" width="200"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Glad to help @NehaManchal

Answer (score 0):

Simply target the img in the wrapper directly  `.wrapper img` and apply the border shadow and the border-radius to it

```css
   

 body {
      background: #F6F6F6;
    }

.wrapper {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      margin-top: 40px;
   
  
    }
    .wrapper img{
      border: 6px solid #19ab8c;
      border-radius: 100%;
     box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
  
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/567285191169687553/7kg_TF4l.jpeg" width="200"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set wrapper to overflow: hidden;

See bellow

```css
body {
  background: #F6F6F6;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 6px solid #19ab8c;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/567285191169687553/7kg_TF4l.jpeg" width="200"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you

```
.wrapper { 
border: 6px solid #19ab8c; 
border-radius: 100%; 
margin: 0 auto; 
margin-top: 40px; 
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc; 
}

.wrapper img {
width:100%;
height:auto;
}
```

**Solution 2:**

And one more thing remove width height from wrapper div or increase both as per your image size

**Solution 3:**

You can also fix the width and height on image tag like and remove from wrapper class.

```
<img width="200" height="200" src="">
```